# Uploaded file in ApiTestCase is not set in the controller-side request

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

**API Platform version(s) affected**: 2.5.7

When making a request in an ApiTestCase with a FormDataPart, the `$request->files` is empty on the controller side.

Here is my test :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\DataPart;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\Multipart\FormDataPart;

class ImportRequestTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testPostOk(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $data = ['file' => DataPart::fromPath(__DIR__.'/../path/to/file.csv')];
        $formData = new FormDataPart($data);
        $headers = $formData->getPreparedHeaders();

        $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/import_requests/{my-request-id}/upload',
            [
                'headers' => $headers->toArray(),
                'body' => $formData->bodyToString(),
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(204);
    }
}
```

The related ApiResource :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Controller\ImportRequestUpload;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *    itemOperations={
 *        "get",
 *        "delete",
 *        "put",
 *        "upload"={
 *            "method"="POST",
 *            "path"="/import_requests/{id}/upload",
 *            "controller"=ImportRequestUpload::class,
 *            "deserialize"=false,
 *            "openapi_context"={
 *                "requestBody"={
 *                    "content"={
 *                        "multipart/form-data"={
 *                            "schema"={
 *                                "type"="object",
 *                                "properties"={
 *                                    "file"={
 *                                        "type"="string",
 *                                        "format"="binary"
 *                                    }
 *                                }
 *                            }
 *                        }
 *                    }
 *                }
 *            }
 *        }
 *    },
 *    collectionOperations={
 *        "get",
 *        "post"
 *    }
 * )
*/
final class ImportRequest
{
    // ...
}
```

And my controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\ImportRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

final class ImportRequestUpload
{
    public function __invoke(ImportRequest $data, Request $request)
    {
        /** @var null|UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');

        if (null === $uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required.');
        }

        // ...
        
        return new JsonResponse(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

When running my test, the `ImportRequestUpload` controller is throwing the `BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required.')`.
What's weird is that the content and headers of my request seems ok when I dump them in the controller :

```php
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {
  ...
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#4930
    #parameters: array:25 [
      ...
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=hqdh0ikk"
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
      ...
    ]
  }
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#4931
    #parameters: []
  }
  ...
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#4941
    #headers: array:15 [
      ...
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "multipart/form-data; boundary=hqdh0ikk"
      ]
      ...
    ]
  }
  #content: """
    --hqdh0ikk\r\n
    Content-Type: text/csv\r\n
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="import_ok_1.csv"\r\n
    \r\n
    header1,header2\n
    value1,value2\n
    \r\n
    --hqdh0ikk--\r\n
    """
}
```

If I replace the `$formData->bodyToString()` by `$formData->bodyToIterable()` (as initially suggested in the HttpClient documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data), I get the following error :

```
TypeError : Argument 6 passed to Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\AbstractBrowser::request() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php on line 126
 /srv/api/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/AbstractBrowser.php:341
 /srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php:126
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there any other way to upload a file in an ApiTestCase ?

Thanks for your help.